# Do SQL Server 2008 Cumulative Updates Require a Reboot?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

I have SQL box that I need to apply a CU (specifically #14). Can anyone confirm if a server re-start is needed after this update? I'm hoping that it doesn't need one but I'm guessing that's not likely.

Comment: For future people reading this question - the CU did not require a server re-start but did stop all SQL services for about 5-7 minutes but of course that will vary according to your machine

Comment: The SQL team has been doing a pretty good job lately of allowing you to stop things prior to updating so that you don't have to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Not usually, but the SQL Service will need to stop and restart.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a surprisingly nice development. I was almost certain that I'd have to restart. I might have to pull the trigger on this then. Thanks!

Comment: There's a screen during the installer which will tell you if there are processes running which would cause a reboot.  Just down those services then run the installer.